# How to increase the font size of a pop-up in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm using Android Studio fo Flutter Projects and one thing I would like to improve is the size of the pop-up font in the editor window. I think the same is actual for a java or a kotlin developers. Is there a setting to make the font bigger?

[image]

Comment: Don't spam with irrelevant tags

Comment: well it would be great if more people related to this editor be noticed about the issue

Comment: Irrelevant tags are irrelevant and make noise. Do not spam with irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

Only way to increase the font size is to increase the font size in `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance` Check the "Use custom font" and increase the size.

[image]

Note this will change the font size of IDE itself.

Comment: Can not say it's a good solution because all the ui then looks quite 
sloppy. It is strange they did not provide this setting.

Comment: @rozerro you can request this on https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA